# How to mount express.js sub-apps?

Tags: node.js

I have several apps that I'm trying to merge into a single "suite": 2 apps are standalone, one  is simply an auth layer (using everyauth for FB Connect). I want to set it up like so:

- /  - (home) list of the apps
- /auth  - login for any app
- /app1  - requires login via /auth to access
- /app2  - (same)

I've considered leaving app1 and app2 standalone, with the top layer being a proxy, but I think it would be hard to share an auth system between them.
Virtualhosts (via Connect) might work, but I don't necessarily want a DNS'd subdomain for each one.
So instead I'd like to primary app to be the auth layer, and the others "mounted" into that one, with *basepath* set on each app to a sub-path. (basepath is mentioned in the express [Guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) but not documented well.)

They all use MongoDB, the auth layer uses connect-mongodb for sessions, so I'm hoping they'll be able to share the whole auth/session layer between them.

In another thread, ["How to share sessions in mounted express apps"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650981/how-to-share-sessions-in-mounted-express-apps), Stephen writes,

> I have a fairly complex express based web application that is split up into a few sub apps which are also express apps (using app.use()) ...

So how does one use `app.use()` to mount a sub-app? I was simply trying to use `var subApp = require('./subapp/app.js')`, with `listen()` running only in the sub-app when `! module.parent` (so not as a sub-app)... but that seems to load all the sub-app's paths straight into the parent app. I've tried setting `basepath` using `app.set('basepath', '/subapp/')`, `app.basepath = '/subapp/'`, etc, both in the sub-app itself and from the parent app, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Mounting apps like this makes express incredibly flexible, but it's not clear how to do it... any advice would be extremely welcome!! (And I'm happy to share lessons from my everyauth implementation if anyone is struggling with that.)

Comment: Correction: I wrote "but that seems to load all the sub-app's paths straight into the parent app", but in fact the sub-app's paths don't seem to be loading anywhere. Only the parent app's paths load. This is via `require('./sub-app/app.js')`.

Comment: A little progress, perhaps: if I `require()` the sub-app into `subApp` and then  `use(subApp)`, it loads the sub-app's paths into the parent app. (As originally described.) `basepath` doesn't seem to modify any paths automatically.

Comment: `q = require('login'); path = 'login' ;app.use('/'+path,x)` , I just wanted to point out that darn leading / is important.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`app.use(uri, instanceOfExpressServer)`

Just make sure you don't call `.listen` on it.

The alternative is to use `require("cluster")` and invoke all your apps in a single master so that they share the same port. Then just get the routing to "just work"

Comment: Thank you! For `uri` I did the relative path '/subapp', and it works!!

Comment: Does `require("cluster")` work on RestifyJS or it will only work for ExpressJS?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this helps you but I was looking to prefix my API routes. What I did was that when I initialized the router, I added the mount path. So my configuration looks like this

```
//Default configuration
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.set('json spaces',0);
    app.use(express.limit('2mb'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use('/api', app.router);
    app.use(function(err, req, res, callback){
        res.json(err.code, {});
    });
});
```

Notice the '/api' when calling the router

Comment: That's pretty clever!