# Running multiple Node (Express) apps on same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have multiple Node applications (build on Express framework).

Now I have placed them like this -

- `/var/www/app1`
- `/var/www/app2`
- `/var/www/app3`

Now I want to run these 3 apps on the same port (say 8080). Is that possible ?

One thing to note is that, Each app has common routes like these -

- `app.get('/', func...);`
- `app.get('/about', func...);`
- `app.post('/foo', func...);`
- `app.post('/bar', func...);`

Basically I want to do it like you can do with Apache/PHP setup.

So with a LAMP stack when you have -

- `/var/www/app1`
- `/var/www/app2`
- `/var/www/app3`

You can easily access them as different apps from -

- `localhost/app1`
- `localhost/app2`
- `localhost/app3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mount express.js sub-apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514106/how-to-mount-express-js-sub-apps)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use [`app.use()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use):

```
app
  .use('/app1', require('./app1/index').app)
  .use('/app2', require('./app2/index').app)
  .listen(8080);
```

Comment: Will this possible if my Node apps were made using Restify? *Ask me if this question isn't specific or clear enough.*

Comment: No, `app.use()` is specific to `express` and will not support any HTTP server that does not follow the express plugin calling pattern.

Comment: I'm guessing that if one app crashes, the rest will too.

Comment: What is the best way to do it without third-party framework like Express.js?

Comment: You can host all your node js apps on different port and then setup a proxy using Nginx.

Answer (score 37):

You could run them as seperate apps listening to different ports and then have a proxy (like https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/ ) serving everything on 8080 depending on the requested URL.

like:

```
var options = {
  router: {
    'foo.com/baz': '127.0.0.1:8001',
    'foo.com/buz': '127.0.0.1:8002',
    'bar.com/buz': '127.0.0.1:8003'
  }
};
```

Works like charm for me ( http://nerdpress.org/2012/04/20/hosting-multiple-express-node-js-apps-on-port-80/). I wasn't so keen on having them mounted as sub-apps, as suggested in the comments because i wanted them to run independently...

Comment: First of all, i don't want to setup multiple vhosts. i want it like vhost/app1 , vhost/app2 , vhost/app3. secondly, i tried the second method from the blog post you linked to, but it's not really working for me and i don't know whether it'll fit my use case or not. any idea ? oh, and also not looking to use a reverse proxy at this point...

Comment: Of course you can run your subapps wrapped in one app and handle the routing internally. 

I personally just don't like my apps depend on each other that much, when it comes to crashes. Thats why i prefer running them on different ports.

Comment: you don't have to set up multiple vhost to achieve this with node-http-proxy , i'll update the answer with an example

Comment: could you clarify how to use the "options" var?

Comment: apparently the `router` in options was removed a while ago. https://blog.nodejitsu.com/node-http-proxy-1dot0/

Answer (score 0):

You can create one main app(say app) parallel to you apps, and have it initializing the secondary apps (in your case app1, app2, app3) using

```
app.use('<the_context_you_need>', require('./app1/yourApp.js')
```

All your apps (app1, app2, app3) need to create app and export it by using

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

You need not create instance of server or call app.listen in all the subapps; all the sub-apps can be served via main app listen port.