# is it possible to make nodejs scripts listen to same port

Tags: node.js

I ask the same question in another thread, but the answer misunderstood my question , thus I ask again

I have two scripts

```
 s1.js, s2.js
```

both use express framework and listen to certain port.

I call

```
node s1.js //listens to port 8080

node s2.js //listens to port 8081
```

to start the two scripts, one listens to port 8080, another listens to port 8081.

is it possible to make nodejs  scripts listen to same port 8080?
how to separate the two scripts when I call

www.abc.com:8080

Your comment welcome

Updated question

I try code app.js

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();

  app.use('/app1', require( './app1/index.js').app);
  app.use('/app2', require( './app2/index.js').app);

  app.listen(8081);
```

in the path ./app1/index.js

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  console.log("app1");
  app.listen(8081);
```

in the path ./app2/index.js

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  console.log("app2");
  app.listen(8081);
```

then I called

```
  node app
```

console reports error:

```
app1

/Users/myname/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:111
  if (fn.handle && fn.set) app = fn;
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined
    at Function.app.use (/Users/zhengwang/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:111:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zhengwang/multi.js:27:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: If it was possible, which of them would handle the response?

Comment: do you mean different nodejs scripts have to listen to different ports and it is must-be?

Comment: for php,  www.abc.com/s1.php www.abc.com/s2.php are listen to same ports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running multiple Node (Express) apps on same port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225983/running-multiple-node-express-apps-on-same-port)

Comment: It's not node.js related. Ports in modern computers are per application, and you start two totally separate applications by running two `node s...` commands.

Comment: you can have a proxy listening to port 8080, forwarding requests to your apps with https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/

Comment: If your server have 2 IPs, you can listen(8080, ip1), listen(8080, ip2). Anyway you should use nginx or something like that in production: users -> nginx port 80 --proxy to--> {app1 port 3000, app2 port 3001}

Comment: @LexPodgorny It **is** possible (how do you think Node.js cluster works?). There are at least two ways: forking and/or passing socket file descriptors between processes (via for example UDP). It is up to OS to decide which process handles `recv`/`accept` on the socket. However in practice it is almost always better to do that with a proxy.

Comment: @freakish Great! Sounds like you know the topic well, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cluster does this, and so does Express.vhost.  You can in fact use both and only use 1 port all together.

```
// server.js
var cluster = require('cluster');
var express = require('express');
var app = express ();

var cpus = require('os').cpus().length - 1;

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for(var i=0;i<cpus;i++) {
        cluster.fork ();
    }
}
else {
    app
        .use( express.vhost('www.site1.com'), require('./site1.js').app ) )
        .use( express.vhost('www.site2.com'), require('./site2.js').app ) )
        .listen(8080);
}
```

In the site1.js, site2.js, you write them out like you'd write any other node app, except for two little things.  Export your app (var app = exports.app = express() ), and don't listen (app.listen(8080)) in those two files.  You can see the server.js already does the listening for you, and also requires the two 'app' exports from them.  Now all your sites on the same server can run on the same port, and on every CPU your server has.  I do believe your server itself needs to be setup correctly too, for multiple vhosts, but that's beyond the question asked.

Cluster deals with sending requests to one of the node apps (server.js) running, then express deals with using the right app (site1.js, site2.js) for the request based on the url used.  Surprisingly simple I'd say.  I do love node.

Comment: I didn't write your code for you, look into how cluster and express.vhost works to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @Chris I really liked your summary in the last paragraph; very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Okey, so here's the truth: **multiple processes can listen on the same port**. There are two cases known to me (only on POSIX):

1) Forking. When a master process listens on a socket and then it forks itself then all children listen on the same socket. This means that multiple processes listen on the same socket. And this actually what [Node.js cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) does. You might want to have a look at it.

2) Passing socket file descriptor between two **independent** processes. Yes, it can be done. However there's a lots of work involved with it. Basically two processes communicate via UDS and one of them passes socket file descriptor to the other, so the other can listen on it as well. However this requires some low level network programming (passing a socket's FD is not as simple as passing it as a message). Here's an example of such implementation in C:

http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2002-January/000292.html

I'm not sure though whether 2) can be done with Node.js.

Note that in both cases it is up to OS to load balance between processes (it is OS that decides which process handles `accept` and/or `recv` on a socket). As far as I know most OS do their job really well.

However this is really impractical. I've never seen solution 2) used in real life (extremely complex, some serious security issues) and as for solution 1) it was widely used by (for example) Apache web server but nowadays people tend to use threads and/or async systems so forking becomes a bit obsolete (unless you want to take a full advantage of multiple CPU cores - there are no threads in Node.js).

So in your case I guess that the easiest solution would be to put a (ha)proxy in front of both servers so that it will load balance between these two scripts.

Note that the question is weird though. You say that you have two different servers but you want them to listen on the same port. This means that each request will go to one of them. In particular half users will be handled by `s1` while the other half by `s2`. If they are doing the same that why are there two files? If they are doing something else then why would half of users get different result? It seems that you are trying to do something **really** bad.

Comment: The kernel in Windows allows multiple applications to share a port as long as the Url is unique.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I don't understand. How URL is related to port sharing? URL is a piece of HTTP protocol, it is not in kernel. On the other hand I do not know much about Windows' magic.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Ah, I see. Very interesting, thanks. I should've mentioned that I'm only talking about POSIX.

Comment: @freakish `cluster` actually passes fd's as well (through Unix domain sockets, which isn't the same as UDP, by the way), and on POSIX (/UNIX) too you can have multiple processes listening on the same port as long as the *hostname* they bind to is unique.

Comment: @robertklep 1) That's a typo. I've meant UDS (Unix Domain Sockets) - fixed that. That's weird, I've made it in comment as well. User Datagram Protocol is absolutely not related to that at all. 2) I don't know how Node.js works internally but according to docs it just forks itself. I think it would be quite difficult to implement automatic FD sharing (via UDS). I might be wrong though. 3) Yeah, I'm assuming that they both bind to the same hostname.

Comment: @freakish it's explained [in the fine manual](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works) :)

Answer (score -1):

Your /app1/index.js and /app2/index.js should NOT listen(), as app.js already is listening, and they both need to export the app object.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = exports.app = express();
console.log("app1");
```

Ditto for app2/index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = exports.app = express();
console.log("app2");
```

Comment: if port is 80, wonder how to access the index.js in differrent path (app1, app2)

Comment: No reason to access it...all the code for each site goes into those two apps (app1/index.js & app2/index.js)  All your app.get() & app.post() go in those.

Comment: for php, www.abc.com/app1.php www.abc.com/app2.php are normal, this is what I hope nodejs script can do

Comment: If that's all you wanted to do, then this is overkill.