# Fall back to another Express app when the first doesn't match a route

Tags: node.js, express

**TL/DR: Is there a way to combine two apps with express, and fall back to the second app if the first doesn't implement a route?**

We currently have two express apps, a new well-factored app and an old, deprecated app. Going forward, our team will be slowly migrating everything in the old app to the new app.

I'm looking for a way to combine the two apps so they can both be called. I realized I can do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228833/262125) using `app.use`, but that requires the apps to be on separate subdomains or use separate base paths. My goal is to keep the routes the same, so a person calling the API is unaware of the changes happening under the hood.

For example, it would be great if I could do something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
let oldApp = express();
let newApp = express();

oldApp.get('/old', function (req, res) {
  res.send("OLD");
});

newApp.get('/new', function (req, res) {
  res.send("NEW");
});

express().use(oldApp, newAPp).listen(3000);
```

Then, I could call `localhost:3000/old` or `localhost:3000/new` and both endpoints would work.

Comment: The path is optional for `.use`, so you could do `.use(oldApp).use(newApp)`

Comment: Exactly. It might need some work though, e.g. you must remove the 404 handling in `oldApp`. Also I'm not sure whether you can directly `use()` and `express()` instance. You might have to switch to `express.Router()`, in this case you could have problems with some settings (e.g. template engine, etc.).

Comment: @ExplosionPills This worked great! Would you mind adding your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is optional for `.use`. You can apply the middleware and any routes that are handled by that middleware will be used first.

```
express.use(oldApp).use(newApp)
```

If you did `.use(oldApp, newApp)` it would try to interpret `oldApp` as a path.

Comment: Thanks for the help!