# How ot run multiple instances of server and client codes on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming, web-development-server

I am trying to create a network of nodes on my computer that can act like a client and a server. Each node should be running its own instance of server code and client code and should be able to give requests to its own instance of the server. How can I start a server of my own in Node and how can I have them all run on different ports?

Thanks

Comment: `how can I have them all run on different ports` - by specifying which port to use in the code you haven't shown

Comment: Check out the following post, the second answer presents a solution to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225983/running-multiple-node-express-apps-on-same-port

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker with docker compose, you can run all environments you want very easily
https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._