# Multiple NodeJS Application listening the same port in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, webserver, virtualhost

Is there any way to run multiple nodejs applications in a single port ***(80)*** listening to a specific folder?

I mean as a web server for NodeJS applications.

I know that this option exists in Apache with applications in PHP.
I would like to do it in this way, since I need to upload several applications to my server constantly.
for example:

I have my folder called **ServerFolder**, where I will store my applications.

> **ServerFolder/app1/index.js**
>
> **ServerFolder/app2/index.js**

And in my routes I would like to only access my domain with the respective folder application in the following way.

> **localhost/app1**
>
> **localhost/app2**

Answer (score 0):

You can, however you will need to use proxy method in order to redirect to the folder. In node i think you can use Ngex or Apache to proxy it.

https://technology.amis.nl/2018/03/19/node-express-application-to-proxy-http-requests-simply-forwarding-the-response-to-the-original-caller/

Here is a quick read with the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible if you use particular framework - connect/express for example see [Running multiple Node (Express) apps on same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225983/running-multiple-node-express-apps-on-same-port?rq=1)

If not I am afraid there is no generic way to do it. You would have to run all apps as a single app - bind the port 80 and somehow route request to each individual app (based on prefix).

For TCP - unfortunately - there is no way that multiple application can listen on the same port at the same time.