# Can I deploy multiple react apps on the same port ? Admin panel & Front side two react production mode not working same node js api server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

Can I deploy multiple react apps on the same port ? Admin panel & Front side two react production mode not working same node js api  server

Comment: don't think so..but on different ports

Comment: As a short answer would be "no." Because every port number belongs to a specified process in the machine. Nevertheless, you have another options like using Nginx or HAProxy. They are application-level reverse proxy solutions, you can change incoming request's destination by playing HTTP headers, URI, payload in the proxy.

Comment: True, you could have 2 urls pointing at the same computer, but you translate that `url1:80` to `lanIP:2000` and `url2:80` to `lanIP:3000`, I think. This may be an [alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225983/running-multiple-node-express-apps-on-same-port)

Answer (score 1):

No, is not possible.

Another solution is to merge the two projects in one to handle one port or use `nginx` with port forwarding to change the `port` depending from url.