# How to create a website that can be extended through plugins

Tags: node.js, plugins

I'm curious if there are any best practices, libraries, or good ideas for structuring a Node.JS application so that its functionality can be extended through plugins.  The plugins would act much like they do in a common CMS like Wordpress were the user somehow gets the files to a plugin directory and then enables them without having to restart the server.

Thanks for any direction you can give me.  I'm not afraid to reinvent the wheel (it's a lot of fun), but I am quite lazy and would love to find something that does the hard work for me. : )

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing, came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514106/how-to-mount-express-js-sub-apps, but haven't gotten a chance to look closely at it. May be of use to you.

Comment: think bigger... the website is the module  https://github.com/JamesVAndino/rabbit/blob/master/index.js#L50 if you need a cup of tea don`t boil the ocean. if you need to boil an ocean boil the ocean, you have the right idea.